# Find and replace a string in JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the following problem. I would like to find and replace a specific string which I'm getting through AJAX.

**Code:**

JQuery:

```
if(!countflag) {
    $('.panel-body > p').each(function() {
        var content = $(this).find("span").html();

        $.ajax({ 
            url: '/vacatures.php',
            data: {company: content},
            type: 'post',
            success: function(output) {

                var text = $(this).find("span").text();
                $(this).text(text.replace(content, output));

            }
        });


        if(content) {
            countflag = true;
        }
    });
}
```

In the HTML the company ID (for example `c88`) is shown. This needs to be found and replaced by the actual name of the company.

The ID is inside `span` tags. I thought it would make it easier to find and replace the ID.

The AJAX sends a call to `vacatures.php` which sends back the name of the company that corresponds to the ID shown in `.panel-body > p`.

At this point I'm stuck on how to successfully find and replace the ID by the company name.

**UPDATE (The HTML Code - partially):**

[image: HTML Code]

Comment: Please show us the html. Are there multiple company IDs on the page?

Comment: Yes, there are multiple, I'll edit the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having a closure issue... the `this` inside the `success callback` is different from the `this` of the `each callback`... you need to have a look on how closures work in javascript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

by the way, in order to have a fast fix you need to save the first `this` reference:

```js
$('.panel-body > p').each(function() {
  // keep a memory reference of this
  var self = this;
  var item = $(self);
  var content = item.find("span").html();

  $.ajax({ 
    url: '/vacatures.php',
    data: {company: content},
    type: 'post',
    success: function(output) {
      
      var text = item.find("span").text();
      
      // the following expression cannot work because text isn't defined
      item.text(text.replace(content, output));

    }
  });

});
```

notes: the variable `text` seems to be not defined; generally that code needs a refactoring.

Comment: I'm getting the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: self.find is not a function`

Comment: did you do `var self = this` ?

Comment: Yep, I copied the everything from your answer

Comment: That fixed it! I will check for closure next time!

Answer (score -1):

Please let me know if this works

```
if(!countflag) {
    $('.panel-body > p').each(function() {
        var content = $(this).find("span").html();

        $.ajax({ 
            url: '/vacatures.php',
            data: {company: content},
            type: 'post',
            success: function(output) {

               $(this).find("span").html(output)


            }
        });


        if(content) {
            countflag = true;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Then you really do love downvoting right? instead of showing a way??

Comment: As I said, it cannot work because of the closure... basically the expression ` $(this).find("span").html(output)` cannot produce any result because that `this` isn't the same `this` of the `var content = $(this).find("span").html();` expression. For a way you need to have a look at my answer. I downvoted u because your answer is wrong.